# how to remove first and last character of a string if it is special character using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a list like,

```
mylist=["'one'","{two}","'three'","four","{{{five}}}","s*ix"]
```

For each element, I want to remove the first and last character if it is a special character (other than a-z).

My desired output is,

```
 out_list=["one","two","three","four","{{five}}","s*ix"]
```

Comment: You need to define what special is. Are there other characters you don't want?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
mylist=["'one'","{two}","'three'","four","{{{five}}}","s*ix"] 
new_list = list(map(lambda x:re.sub('^[^a-z]|[^a-z]$', '', x), mylist))
```

Output:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', '{{five}}', 's*ix']
```

Edit: to remove elements containing a special character, you can try this:

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda x:not re.findall('^[^a-z]|[^a-z]$', x), mylist))
```

Output:

```
['four', 's*ix']
```

Comment: my original data contains not only these two special character, I want to remove any type of special character

Comment: By special characters, do you mean anything non-letter?

Comment: @pyd can you clarify what constitutes a special character in the scope of this problem?

Comment: other than {a-z}

Comment: @pyd please see my recent edit.

Comment: @Ajax1234 could you pls see my updated question

Comment: @pyd please see my recent edit.

Comment: yes, Thank you for the solution. I will check and acceptit as answer

Comment: @pyd glad to help!

Comment: can you tell me how to remove an item if the item contains a spacial character (other than a-z)

Comment: @pyd please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

`r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]'` this is everything except numbers and letters, and `re.sub` deletes these. you can put any other character that you want to allow in the regex with `\char`.

```
import re

mylist=["'one'","{two}","'three'","four","{{{five}}}"]

x = [re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', '', i) for i in mylist]

print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
mylist=["'one'","{two}","'three'","four","{{{five}}}"]
newlist=[]
for e in mylist:
    if e[0] not in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm":
        newlist.append(e[1:-1])
```

Or shorter:

```
[e[1:-1] if e[0] not in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" else e for e in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a translation table to translate unwanted characters to empty strings

```
import string, operator
table = str.maketrans({c:'' for c in string.punctuation})
a = ["'one'","{two}","'three'","four","{{{five}}}","s*ix"]
```

Translate the first and last characters, and reconstruct.

```
#helpers for readability
first = operator.itemgetter(0)
last = operator.itemgetter(-1)
middle = slice(1,-1)
for thing in a:
    beginning = first(thing).translate(table)
    mid = thing[middle]
    end = last(thing).translate(table)
    print(''.join([beginning, mid, end]))
```